# why doesn't make -C change $PWD as seen through a scripting language such as Perl?

Tags: perl, gnu-make

Here is `temp/Makefile`:

```
all:
    echo $$PWD
    echo $(CURDIR)
    perl -e 'print $$ENV{"PWD"}'
```

and now

```
$make -C temp
make: Entering directory `/home/mgaleck/temp'
/home/mgaleck/temp
/home/mgaleck/temp
/home/mgaleck
make: Leaving directory `/home/mgaleck/temp'
```

Why is the third value without `temp`?

According to Make manual, `-C` option causes to "change the directory" (working directory?) first.

Same thing happens with Python.

Answer (score 3):

Because the `PWD` environment variable doesn't hold the current working directory; it holds *whatever the current working directory was the last time `sh` set it*. Anything other than a shell starting up, or a shell executing the `cd` builtin (or a similar builtin like `pushd`, in shells that have it), has no effect on `PWD`, and relying on `PWD` anywhere except in the shell is probably a silly idea. Use `getcwd` (C), `Cwd::getcwd` (Perl), `os.getcwd` (Python), etc. instead.

Comment: Well, then why does the first line work? I guess because all Make recipe lines, are executed (as if) by spawning a shell first. So, yes, the shell should have been started every time, and `PWD` should have been set for all 3 lines.  Except, in some cases, GNU Make optimizes, the "as if" behaviour, and does not actually spawn a shell.  

Do you think this is why there is a discrepancy?

Comment: Yes, very likely.  If you want to be more consistent you can always add `PWD := $(CURDIR)` to your makefiles.